# problem when uploading image on my system laravel

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload

**I'm new to programming, I need to upload an image on my website, but when I click the Save button, it returns this error**

> "Call to a member function getRealPath() on null"

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6WZi.jpg)

My Controller

```php
public function NewsInsert(Request $request)
{
    $path = Storage::putFileAs(
        'imagem',
        $request->file('imagem'),
        $request->user()->id
    );
    
    $titulo = $request->get('titulo');
    $texto = $request->get('texto');
            
    $data = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    
    DB::table('noticias')->insert([
        'titulo' => $titulo,
        'imagem' => $path,
        'texto' => $texto,
        'slug' => $titulo,
        'data' => $data
    ]);
    
    return redirect('News');
}
```

My View

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <form method="POST" action="NewsInserir">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-email-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Titulo</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo da Noticia" type="text" value="" id="titulo" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Selecione uma imagem: <input name="imagem" type="file" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-email-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Noticia</label>
    <div class="col-10">
      <textarea name="texto" id="texto" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <center>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Postar Noticia</button>
  </center>
```

Comment: is the file even as a file in your request what happens if you dd($request)?

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` should be on the `<form>` tag. `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"... >`

Comment: return the same error

Comment: putFileAs"
array:3 [▼
  0 => "file"
  1 => null
  2 => 3
]

Answer (score 0):

When you make a `POST` request, you have to encode the data that forms the body of the request in some way.

Use `multipart/form-data` when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.
So `enctype="multipart/form-data"` should be on the `<form>` tag instead on your `<div>`.

Comment: is correct ?

<form method="POST" action="NewsInserir">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group row">
  <label for="example-email-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Titulo</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input class="form-control" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo da Noticia" type="text" value="" id="titulo" required>
  </div>
</div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Selecione uma imagem: <input name="file" type="file" />
   
        <div class="form-group row">

Comment: No, you can't have a form within a form. The right way is to leave one form. And inside all the fields.

```<form action="NewsInserir" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
</form>```